# Is there a reason Finder opens separate Info window for group of files/folders I have selected?

Tags: finder

In most of the cases when I select couple of folders and want to get info on them, I want to know how much space do they take. I was surprised that Finder opens Info window for each selected file/folder instead of give me info on what I selected in one window.

I know that I can use Summary Info after pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>, but what is the use case for default behavior?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asking about why Apple does/doesn't do something.

Comment: JBis, thanks for your comment, but it's not about Apple doing or not doing something, I'm just looking for a use case when it's actually useful. As a user I didn't expect that to happen and do't understand how to use it, that is why I decided to ask

Comment: @IhorBats: I believe that "why" it's done like this would be the same answer as your other question. But you may wish to check out the different "views" available in `Finder`: list (a la Explorer), icons, columns or ''Cover Flow". Again, once you actually invest the time in learning, I believe you'll find your opinion that "Explorer" is the best way to manage files and folders now is illusory.

Comment: @IhorBats Again, welcome! :) Just to clarify (for future reference), while I understand why new users may see questions like this as *not about Apple doing or not doing something*, many would say it is because it is Apple who designs the OS and therefore it's effectively about *why Apple designed the OS in this way*? In this case, my guess is that if you were used to macOS and switched to Windows you'd be wondering why Windows did it differently. :)

Comment: As an advanced user of both Windows and macOS (am I allowed to say that LOL), each have their advantages. But to answer your question, the default in macOS provides a quick way to view detailed properties for each of the folders separately, rather than lumping everything together and not having that breakdown which could be very meaningful.

Comment: **Close Voters:**  This is a perfectly valid question about the workflow of a Finder function and not a philosophical "Why Apple did this/that/other thing"  Voting to **Leave Open**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that I can use Summary Info after pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>, but what is the
>   use case for default behavior?

**It's working as expected.**

The action that you select is operating on each file individually.  If you consider the other Finder functions (i.e. when you right click after selecting multiple files/folders), each function operates on each file individually.

- Rename - renames *each* file/folder
- Duplicate - duplicates *each* file/foler
- Quick View - opens dialog for *each* file/folder
- Compress - adds *each* file/folder to a zip archive
- Share - shares *each* file via messaging, email, etc.

Look at it in this manner - Finder doesn't do a single operation over many files, it does one operation on each file for as many files selected.

The reason Summary Info is there, is for this exact reason, so you can get the aggregated info of many files because the default action is to operate on the folders/files individually.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that is the answer I was looking for, I have couple more questions similar to this one, regarding workflow of Finder. 
**Close Voters:** I don't think you have to close it either, it's very close to the questions that violate some of the rules but it is different. The fact that it was viewed more than 20 times and only one person was able to give answer for it means something. That is kind of knowledge I expected to get from this forum, **I'm looking for understanding of not only HOW it works but WHY it works one way or another**
Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help and feel free to post questions if you can't find someone who's already asked or you didn't get a satisfactory answer.

Comment: could you please check this question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334460/file-management-workflow-in-macos-and-creation-of-files

Comment: I voted to reopen.  It's a decent question about workflow and can be answered (here) in one word:  consistency.  Once it opens up, I'll post an answer.